# Change Products Images Dimensions in Catalog List Magento 2.1.6

Tags: grid, catalog, list

I need to change the size of the images shown in the **LIST** format, but leaving the **GRID** format like this.

The first image shows how the page is currently in **LIST** mode.

The second image shows how I would like the products to be displayed

And the third image shows how the **GRID** is, **I don't want to edit it!**

**First Image**

[image: ActualList]

**Second Image**

[image: ObjetiveList]

**Third Image**

[image: Grid]

I would appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

open your themes "view.xml file ( can be found in Company/Theme-Name/etc/ folder of your themes package ) and find the code below :

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
     <width>400</width>
     <height>400</height>
</image>
```

here you can change the width and height as per your requirements, this will change image size on category format only.

Comment: I changed them! But it is not reflected on the page. . . It may be that I have to change the size assigned to the product instead of resizing the photo?

Comment: @Elet, after that flush cache and generate the static content again. did you try that too ?